# How many CPU cycles are "lost" by adding an extra function call in Java

Tags: java, android, performance, compiler-optimization

How many CPU cycles are "lost" by adding an extra function call in Java?
Are there compiler options available that transform many small functions into one big function in order to optimize performance?

E.g.

```
void foo() {
  bar1()
  bar2()
}

void bar1() {
  a();
  b();
}
void bar2() {
  c();
  d();
}
```

Would become:

```
void foo() {
  a();
  b();
  c();
  d();
}
```

Comment: The Java compiler is pretty 'dumb'. The JVM will at runtime optimize depending on the machine it is running on, the runtime characteristics of the code (eg which code is 'hot', etc), and other factors. Not sure if and how that applies to Android.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is to write readable code (saving possibly hundreds of hours in developer time when fixes are needed) and if, **only if**, a profiler says that the [code-in-question] is taking too long to do [thing], then you optimize [thing] out

Comment: @CarsonGraham Why not try to do both?

Answer (score 3):

> How many cpu cycles are "lost" by adding an extra function call in Java?

This depends on whether it is inlined or not. If it's inline it will be nothing (or a notional amount)

If it is not compiled at runtime, it hardly matters because the cost of interperting is more important than a micro optimisation, and it is likely to be not called enough to matter (which is why it wasn't optimised)

The only time it really matters is when the code is called often, however for some reason it is prevented from being optimised.  I would only assume this is the case because you have a profiler telling you this is a performance issue, and in this case manual inlining might be the answer.

I designed, develop and optimise latency sensitive code in Java and I choose to manually inline methods much less than 1% of time, but only after a profiler e.g. Flight Recorder suggests there is a significant performance problem.

> In the rare event it matters, how much difference does it make?

I would estimate between 0.03 and 0.1 micros-seconds in real applications for each extra call, in a micro-benchmark it would be far less.

> Are there compiler options available that transform many small functions into one big function in order to optimize performance?

Yes, in fact what could happen is not only are all these method inlined, but the methods which call them are inlined as well and none of them matter at runtime, but only if the code is called enough to be optimised. i.e. not only is `a`,`b`, `c` and `d` inlined and their code but `foo` is inlined as well.

By *default* the Oracle JVM can line to a depth of 9 levels (until the code gets more than 325 bytes of byte code)

> Will clean code help performance

The JVM runtime optimiser has common patterns it optimises for. Clean, simple code is generally easier to optimise and when you try something tricky or not obvious, you can end up being much slower. If it harder to understand for a human, there is a good chance it's hard for the optimiser to understand/optimise.

Answer (score 2):

Runtime behavior and cleanliness of code (a compile time or life time property of code) belong to different requirement categories. There might be cases where optimizing for one category is detrimental to the other.

The question is: which category really needs you attention?

In my view cleanliness of code (or malleability of software) suffers from a huge lack of attention. You should focus on that first. And only if other requirements start to fall behind (e.g. performance) you inquire as to whether that's due to how clean the code is. That means you need to really compare, you need to measure the difference it makes. With regard to performance use a profiler of your choice: run the "dirty" code variant and the clean variant and check the difference. Is it markedly? Only if the "dirty" variant is significantly faster should you lower the cleanliness.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following piece of code, which compares a code that does 3 things in one for loop to another that has 3 different for loops for each task.

```
  @Test
  public void singleLoopVsMultiple() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

      //single loop
      int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
      long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        x++;
        y++;
        z++;
      }
      l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;


      //multiple loops doing the same thing
      int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
      long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        a++;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        b++;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        c++;
      }
      m = System.currentTimeMillis() - m;
      System.out.println(String.format("%d,%d", l, m));

    }
  }
```

When I run it, here is the output I get for time in milliseconds.

```
6,5
8,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
```

After a few runs, JVM is able to identify hotspots of intensive code and optimises parts of the code to make them significantly faster. In our previous example, after 2 runs, the JVM had already optimised the code so much that the discussion around for-loops became redundant.

Unless we know what's happening inside, we cannot predict the performance implications of changes like introduction of for-loops. The only way to actually improve the performance of a system is by measuring it and focusing only on fixing the actual bottlenecks.

There is a chance that cleaning your code may make it faster for the JVM. But even if that is not the case, every performance optimisation, comes with added code complexity. Ask yourself whether the added complexity is worth the future maintenance effort. After all, the most expensive resource on any team is the developer, not the servers, and any additional complexity slows the developer, adding to the project cost.

The way to deal it is to figure out your benchmarks, what kind of application you're making, what are the bottlenecks. If you're making a web-app, perhaps the DB is taking most of the time, and reducing the number of functions will not make a difference. On the other hand, if its an app running on a system where performance is everything, every small thing counts.